# Xdebug and Netbeans "Waiting for connection" but never connects

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

**Note, that the problem solved itself already, but you can take it as an example for a working configuration of Xdebug within the php.ini file!!!**

---

I'm new to Netbeans and PHP and after 5 days into a project I realized that I really need a Debugger ^^
So now I am trying to set Xdebug up with Netbeans, but it's just not working.....

So far I read many articles here in the forum and elsewhere in the internet, but still after using all those adoptions....still nothing.

**Ok, here is my configuration:
Windows7, Netbeans 7.2, PHP Version 5.4.4, XAMPP 1.8.0.**

### What I did so far:

1. clean installation of XAMPP (keeping the old htdocs and mysql, the project) and running phpinfo() and posting its content into the wizzard
2. then following the instructions from [xdebug wizard](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php)

   - Move the downloaded file to C:\xampp\php\ext
   - Edit C:\xampp\php\php.ini and add the line zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9.dll Restart the webserver
3. in one post someone mentioned that the filename "php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9.dll" sometime is not accepted so I **changed it to "php_xdebug.dll" and so replaced the already existing one**

-after editing the php.ini it now looks like this, the rest of the Xdebug is commented out:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "xdebug_profile.%R::%u"
xdebug.remote_enable =On
xdebug.remote_handler =dbgp
xdebug.remote_host =127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_mode =req
xdebug.remote_port =9000
xdebug.idekey = "netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_autostart =On
```

-Apache and MySQL are running and green in the XAMPP controle panel

#

So now, with all these changes I run the Wizard again, but still tells me to install the Xdebug!
Also searching the phpInfo() output doesn't return any Xdebug stuff......

Now, I start Netbeans and set some breakpoints, start the debug (settings in netbeans, port:9000, SessionID:netbeans-xdebug).
Netbeans is trying to connect.....but nothng happends!

Some Info out of the phpInfo():

```
Zend Extension  220100525
Zend Extension Build    API220100525,TS,VC9
```

Any help would be appreciated

---

---

**

**Ok WOW!!!** After 5h of work and after finishing this post, **I just tried to run the debugger "one last time" :) and it "started" working........cruel world** :D But at least now I can contribute, **that this is a working configuration ;)**

**